# Crystal Reports Merge Module for Visual Studio 2008

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, merge-module

Visual Studio 2008 did not include Merge Modules for Crystal Reports. This means that if you upgraded your Windows Forms application from 2005 to 2008 the reporting application would no longer work on client machines.

There are a number of conflicting reports over the web about the status of this - whether a merge module will be or has been released or not.

I followed the advice of [this forum](http://gery.vessere.com/2008/04/05/crystal-reports-in-visual-studio-2008-no-more-merge-modules), and downloaded merge modules from 
[HREF=https://smpdl.sap-ag.de/~sapidp/012002523100005986132008E/cr10_net_mm.zip](https://smpdl.sap-ag.de/~sapidp/012002523100005986132008E/cr10_net_mm.zip)

I've created an installation file containing the CrystalReports10_Net_EmbeddedReporting.msm merge module. I could create an installation, but my application still didn't work (see the bottom of this message for the error). My guess is that this is for those who have purchased Crystal Reports as a separate package to Visual Studio, as opposed to those who are using the bundled version.

Has anyone else successfully utilised a merge module for Crystal Reports that comes bundled with Visual Studio 2008?

Note that I can install the application "CRRedist2008_x86.msi" that comes with Visual Studio 2008 professional. (Look in Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\CrystalReports10_5). But I want a Merge Module, so that the customers do not have to install two separate packages.

---

The error I get is

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms,
>   Version=10.5.3700.0, Cultrue=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the file specified

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while, and it seems the links have changed, but I've definately used merge modules for VS2008 Crystal Reports.

Did you check [here?](http://resources.businessobjects.com/support/additional_downloads/runtime.asp#09)

Edit:  Actually I could be getting confused with the 2008 redistributable and the 2005 merge modules (Before your edit it looked like the link would give what you wanted). This link definately makes it look like the merge modules don't exist.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't checked there. Looking at it now... under "Crystal Reports Basic for Visual Studio .NET 2008" it gives a ZIP file, but this only contains a .MSI file, not a .MSM file.

Comment: This is the ultimate link to all CR:
https://websmp130.sap-ag.de/sap(bD1lbiZjPTAwMQ==)/bc/bsp/spn/bobj_download/main.htm

Comment: I know this post is old but, I wanted to thank you for your link @KMoraz.  It was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

http://resources.businessobjects.com/support/communityCS/FilesAndUpdates/cr10_net_merge_modules.zip

Answer (score 0):

I had this EXACT error! I worked on this for ages. The zip file you need is cr_net_2005_mergemodules_mlb_x86.zip

Also, you could try changing your compiling options from "any CPU" to "x86".

Comment: I should add: the 2005 redistributable didn't work for me, and I think you had to uninstall and reinstall it before it installed the 10.2.3600 version of the required DLLs into the GAC.

Answer (score 0):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vscrystalreports/thread/b70c896a-6844-48bb-a966-63a3f589a0f1

Answer (score 0):

**Here you will files to download merger modules for VS.Net 2008: http://resources.businessobjects.com/support/additional_downloads/runtime.asp#09**