# Could not load CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc

Tags: crystal-reports

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=10.5.3700.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

---

I just deployed our web app to a new server that uses the Crystal Report viewer in several reports in our ASP.NET 3.5 app. I have all the DLLs CR requires or so I think, in the BIN folder but I am still running into this error. I've never used CR before so do I need to install anything on the server for the reports to work? This is straight out of VS2008.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to install Crystal on the server using the provided msi for the vs2008 version...

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\CrystalReports10_5\CRRedist2008_x86.msi`

Installing this will add the required CR assemblies to the GAC. You should not add them to your app's bin folder.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128904/crystal-reports-merge-module-for-visual-studio-2008) may be of interest.

Comment: dotjoe, I was able to resolve the issues based on your comment. Thank you soooo much!